# Postgresql , updating existing table row with another tables data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to update a null column using another tables value but it doesn't seems to work right. below codes were tried

```
SET 
"Test name "= "Test"(
    SELECT Transformertest.Test,Transformertest.TestID
    FROM public.Transformertest WHERE TestID='Tes3')
WHERE test2table.Type='Oil Immersed Transformers'
```

```
UPDATE
  public.test2table
SET
  "Test name" = subquery."Test"
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      "Test"
    FROM Transformertest  WHERE "TestID"='Tes2'
  ) AS subquery
WHERE
 "Type"='Auto Transformer' AND "Phase"='3' AND "Rated Frequency"='60';
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBwbk.png)

Comment: First of all, `Phase` and `Rated Frequency` are both integers so you should write `AND "Phase"=3 AND "Rated Frequency"=60`

Answer (score 0):

1. don't use space in column name.
2. Integers don't need to be quoted

See the result here ([enter link description here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b4G7ZB8zkvC8ijveQx9CY1/0))

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do here (assuming `Phase` and `Rated Frequency` are integers)
remove unnecessary `""` and spaces on column names

```
UPDATE
  public.test2table
SET
  test_name = subquery.Test
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      test
    FROM Transformertest  WHERE Test_ID='Tes2'
  ) AS subquery
WHERE
 Type='Auto Transformer' AND Phase=3 AND Rated_Frequency=60;
```

this should be working now

Comment: The dreaded double quotes are necessary as long as the names were created with them. Your solution will require to rename the tables and columns (which is a good thing to do)